# Can I get a clear summary of how and when each part of a chef cookbook is loaded/executed?

Tags: chef, documentation

Here's what a chef cookbook looks like:

```
.
├── attributes
│   ├── default.rb
│   └── bla.rb
├── files
│   ├── default
│   │   └── some_file.txt
│   └── windows
│       └── some_file.txt
├── libraries
│   ├── mylib.rb
│   └── default.rb
├── providers
│   ├── default.rb
│   └── foo.rb
├── recipes
│   ├── bar.rb
│   └── default.rb
├── resources
│   ├── default.rb
│   └── foo.rb
└── templates
    ├── default
    │   └── some_template.erb
    └── windows
        └── some_template.erb
```

I went through [the docs](http://docs.opscode.com/), but I'm still confused about how and when each part of a chef cookbook is loaded/executed, and whether it's automatic (and if so in what order?) or on-demand.  Could you please provide a summary or point to one?

I'm specifically confused about the logic for loading files under the `attributes`, `libraries`, `providers`, `recipes` and `resources` directories.  They all contain a `default.rb` file, but it seems that in some cases it's automatically loaded (for attributes, for example), and in some cases it is not (for recipes, for example).  There's a [page in the doc](http://docs.opscode.com/chef/essentials_cookbook_attribute_files.html#cookbook-attribute-file-ordering) about the order in which attribute files are loaded, but it's not clear in what order within the `attributes` directory.  It's not clear to me why you would want to have attribute files other than `default.rb` (it seems that most cookbooks only use `default.rb`).  What would the use-case be?

Perhaps I should ask separate questions, but I thought it might be useful for other chef-newbies to have a summary here.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a fairly complex question and often the hardest part of Chef to wrap your brain around. I found this podcast very helpful.

http://foodfightshow.org/2013/06/episode-53-chef-internals-with-dan-deleo.html